# rake db:migrate YAML parser error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, yaml

I use ruby 1.9.2 and rake 0.9.2.2 on Ubuntu.

When I want to

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error message

```
rake aborted!
couldn't parse YAML at line 89 column 16
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:205:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:171:in `load_yml'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:157:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57:in `init_translations'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:71:in `lookup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:26:in `translate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n.rb:156:in `block in translate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `catch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/i18n-0.6.0/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `translate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:102:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/ralv/devapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:193:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I can solve the problem by commenting out the 89th line of my locale file:

```
open_tasks: %{total} (%{count} offen)
```

But it's quite annoying to do this everytime I want to migrate the database...

The problem seems to be the blank character in front of the first percent sign. If I change the line to

```
open_tasks: (%{total} (%{count} offen)
```

I can migrate without an abortion.

How can I avoid this parser error?

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quotes for complex values

```
open_tasks: "%{total} (%{count} offen)"
```